# Dealing with "white speckles" within QR code images with ZXing

Tags: image, image-processing, zxing, qr-code

I'm running into failures when scanning laser or ink-jet printed QR codes which I'm guessing is to due a combination of less than solid ink/toner coverage and the image processing parameters I'm using in each of two conversion steps that I have control over. I've come up with a "solution" of sorts, but I don't know how robust it is and I'd like to understand both what's going on and whether there's a more reliable approach.

I don't have control over the PDF files I'll be receiving as input and I don't know of any tools to reliably let me examine images within the PDF samples I have, but I'm pretty sure the samples are grey level images of some sort. Here, for example, is a screen snapshot of a corner of one of the QR code cells using Acrobat Reader with its magnification cranked way up.  I'm assuming that the fuzzy circles inside the black represent a single "light" pixel within the image.

[image]

To turn the PDF into a PNG file, I use ghostscript with `sDevice=pnggrey`. After ZXing was unable to recognize the QR codes with an output resolution of 200 dpi, I changed the output resolution to 100 dpi and it succeeded, presumably because by averaging the light pixels with a greater number of surrounding black pixels, the resulting level was below the threshold that was subsequently used to turn the image into the monochrome image that ZXing works on.

The subsequent image processing steps are from the ZXing.rb Ruby gem and consist of calls to `LuminanceSource` and `GlobalHistogramBinarizer` from ZXing. The latter uses a single, global black point for binarization and suggests a `HybridBinarizer` for desktop applications, but since the images were failing on the online version of ZXing as well, I didn't bother experimenting with `HybridBinarizer'.

200 dpi (failing) image:

[image: 200 dpi image]

100 dpi (succeeding) image:

[image]

**Update:** I tried scan converting the PDF at 600 dpi and that succeeded as well. Intrigued, I then took a picture of the printed image with my mobile phone and here's a blown up version of one of the modules in the resulting JPEG:

[image]

As expected, the mobile phone QR code app had no problem recognizing the image from just about any angle and distance.

**Update 2** Here is a look at a couple of codes from the (succeeding) 600dpi (PNG) image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really the difference between dithering and grayscale. The library has a deep assumption that the images are photo-like, and that black-white boundaries look like a continuous change from black to white through shades of gray. Images where the black-white border has been dithered into a checkerboard pattern of black and white to represent gray don't work well since these are interpreted as many tiny black-white transitions when there is just one.

The best thing is to avoid the dithering stage wherever it occurs in the pipeline, but it may be out of your control. If so, then your best bet is down-sampling or blur filter, which is what you've already seen. The 100 dpi image works since the speckled region collapses.

I don't think the binarizers will make much difference to this situation.

Comment: As always, I appreciate your prompt and thoughtful response, Sean. Since an increasing percentage of printed materials are produced by digital devices which really on a combination of binary imaging and halftoning to achieve grey/color variation, I assume that the semi-continuous nature of the photographs you are referring to is more a function of camera-motion-induced or synthesized blur than it is a property of the underlying image. See updated question with more info.

Comment: Yes, an image from a hand-held camera will always have enough low-level motion blur and inexact focus to wash out halftoning. Downsampling or a light blur filter are a cheap way to achieve the same effect when needed.

Comment: +1 for your help, Sean. Downsampling seems cheapest/easiest, but can you provide any guidelines for how to set it so as to maximize resolution while still eliminating the halftoning problem? Also, can you explain why increasing resolution from 200 to 600 worked as well?

Comment: Since the halftone dots are 1 pixel, presumbly, I would imagine that resizing to 50% of the original size is a good place to start. 2 pixels will collapse into 1. I don't know about the 600dpi case, I suppose I wasn't clear whether the halftoning is smaller or larger in that case.

Comment: To clarify, the halftoning is only occurring when the paper is printed and nothing is changing in that printing process, just as nothing is changing when the printed page is scanned to PDF. The resolution is being set as ghostscript parameter when the PDF file is converted to a PNG file. Since the output format in that case is always greyscale, no halftoning is occurring. I added a second update to include the results of the 600dpi rendering of the PDF to PNG.

Comment: As for the size of the halftone dots, they vary, of course, based on the gray level being approximated at that point in the image. But you can look at the 600dpi rendering and see that the smallest appears to be 2x2. (Note: The printing device for the QR code in question was a 600dpi laser printer).